# basic html: why aren't my labels checking my checkboxes?

Tags: html, css

Can't see what I'm doing wrong?!!! gotta be the numerical names right?

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="187" />
    <label for="187">Easily accessible</label><br />   
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="311" />
    <label for="311">WiFi Internet</label><br />   
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="351" />
    <label for="351">Child friendly</label><br />   
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="352" />
    <label for="352">Pets welcome</label><br />   
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="353" />
    <label for="353">Pet free zone</label><br />   
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a text string instead of the numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the for attribute of label should point to an elements id and not it's name (think of the case where two elements have the same name).
I.e.
Using

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="187" />
<label for="187">Easily accessible</label><br />
```

Comment: While this is technically the correct answer (`for` should point to `id`), this is syntactically invalid. In HTML it's illegal to start element ID's with a number. Whether it works depends on how forgiving the webbrowser is.

Comment: @BalusC Ah was not aware that starting IDs was the wrong thing to do.

Comment: HTML5 actually allows starting an ID with a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="cb_187" id="cb_187" />
<label for="cb_187">Easily accessible</label>
```

1. Use both the `name` and `id` attributes (populate them with the same value).
2. Don't start names or IDs with a digit.

Answer (score 2):

As Jim pointed out, the `for` attribute on the `label` should point to the `id` attribute on the `input`.

Alternatively, I prefer just wrapping the `input` and the text inside the label, like so:

`<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="353" /> Pet free zone</label><br />`

That way, you don't have to muck about with `for` and `id`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use more simpler

```
<fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="187" />
    Easily accessible</label>
    ...   
</fieldset>
```

Less code and no need to define a checkbox id. To space text label from checkbox just define a margin-right for `input` field. Give also display : block to the label, so you won't even need of `<br>`